# Generate PDF with Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

So I am trying to generate a PDF with swift. I have been trying to convert from objective C to swift and for now there is some errors that I don't know how to fix.

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func createPDFOnClick(sender: AnyObject!)
{
    pageSize = CGSizeMake(850,1100)
    let fileName: String = "makeME.pdf"
    var path: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,true)
    let documentDirectory: String = path[0] as! String
    let pdfPathWithFileName: String = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingString(fileName)
    self.createPDF(pdfPathWithFileName)

}

func createPDF(filePath: String){

 UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath,CGRectZero,nil)
 UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0,0,850,1100),nil)
 self.drawBackground()
 self.drawText()
 UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

}

func drawBackground() {
    let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,pageSize!.width,pageSize!.height)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(context,rect)
}

func drawText() {
    var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    var textRect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,[[self myTextView]frame].size.with, self.myTextView.frame.size.height)
    var myString: String = self.myTextView.text!
    myString.drawInRect(textRect)
}
```

My errors are the following lines:

> var path: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true)

I getting error "use of unresolved identifier"

> var textRect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,[[self myTextView]frame].size.with, self.myTextView.frame.size.height)

Here i am getting "expect separator"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your errors have little to do with PDF creation and are related to Swift Syntax.

1. The parameters specifying the directory is imported to Swift as an `enum`. So for the directory, your input should be some case of [`NSSearchPathDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDirectory), such as `NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory` (Or more succinctly `.DocumentDirectory`). [`NSSearchPathDomainMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDomainMask) is a `struct` with static constants, so it gets treated like a `struct`. For example, `NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask` (or more succinctly `.UserDomainMask`).
2. Your second parameter is not Swift syntax. Try:

   `var textRect = CGRect(0,0,self.myTextView.frame.size.width, self.myTextView.frame.size.height)`

Comment: In my drawText function on the last row **myString.drawInRect(textRect)** I am getting error **Cannot convert value of type 'CGRect' to expected argument type**.

Comment: What does it say the expected argument type is? If it doesn't, delete that line and retype it, but let the `drawInRect` function autocomplete and see what the parameter placeholder says.